# Abstract type and path dependent type in scala

Tags: scala, types, path-dependent-type, abstract-type

I'd like to use abstract type and type refinement to encode something like a functional dependency between two types.

```
trait BaseA {
  type M
  type P <: BaseB.Aux[M]

  def f(m: M): Unit
}

trait BaseB {
  type M
  def m(): M
}

object BaseB {
  type Aux[M0] = BaseB { type M = M0 }
}
```

It means that a `A` only works with a `B` if they have the same type `M` inside. 
With the following concret classes

```
class A extends BaseA {
  type M = Int
  type P = B

  def f(m: Int): Unit = {
    println("a")
  }
}

class B extends BaseB {
  type M = Int
  def m(): M = 1
}
```

So now they have both `Int` type as `M`, but the following code does not compile

```
val a: BaseA = new A
val b: BaseB = new B

def f[T <: BaseA](a: T, b: T#P): Unit = {
  a.f(b.m())
}
```

The compiler tells me that `a.f` here expect a path dependent type `a.M` but it got a `b.M`.

My question here is how can I express the fact that I only need the `M` type matched in the type level, not the instance level? Or how can I prevent the `M` in `def f(m: M): Unit` becoming a path-dependent type?

Thanks!

Comment: *Why* do you want it to be matched "only on type level", why not just make the type of argument `b` dependent on `a`? For example, `def f[T <: BaseA](a: T)(b: a.P): Unit` works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* the issue comes from `b` being related to a type `T`, and it being possible for `a` to be a *subclass* of `T` that could override `M` to be something else, making the two objects incompatible. For instance:

```
class A2 extends BaseA {
  type M = String
  type P = B2
  def f(s: String): Unit = {
    println(s)
  }
}

class B2 extends BaseB {
  type M = String
  def m(): M = "foo"
}

val a: BaseA = new A
val b: BaseB = new B2

f[BaseA](a, b)
```

It seems like if your `f` were to compile, then all of this should compile too.

You can either make `b`'s type dependent on `a.P`:

```
def f(a: BaseA)(b: a.P): Unit
```

Or I think the whole thing is simplified by not having the compatible types restriction on your classes, but rather require that one is a subclass of the other at the point that they interact:

```
trait BaseA {
  type M
  def f(m: M): Unit
}

trait BaseB {
  type M
  def m(): M
}

class A extends BaseA {
  type M = Int
  def f(m: Int): Unit = {
    println("a")
  }
}

class B extends BaseB {
  type M = Int
  def m(): M = 1
}

val a: A = new A
val b: B = new B

def f(a: BaseA, b: BaseB)(implicit sub: b.M <:< a.M): Unit = {
  a.f(sub(b.m()))
}

f(a, b)
```

Or lastly, consider whether you need these to be path-dependent types at all; could they be regular generic type parameters?

```
trait BaseA[-M] {
  def f(m: M): Unit
}

trait BaseB[+M] {
  def m(): M
}

class A extends BaseA[Int] {
  def f(m: Int): Unit = {
    println("a")
  }
}

class B extends BaseB[Int] {
  def m(): Int = 1
}

def f[T](a: BaseA[T], b: BaseB[T]): Unit = {
  a.f(b.m())
}
```

Comment: My thoughts yesterday went in a similar direction as what you wrote in the first paragraph, but I failed to come up with an example where an actual concrete type was known from the superclass of the class of `a`, and then *overridden* in the subclass. `f[BaseA]` isn't supposed to work, because `BaseA` doesn't fix the type `M` at all. But once you fix it, you can no longer override it, so what you described cannot occur.

Comment: Hmm, good point. Still feels like there should be something that breaks it... but it may also be a case of something that is actually safe, but the compiler just doesn't have the ability to prove that it is.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. The compiler seems unable to prove that the type `M` must be the same, but at the same time it seems clever enough to prevent all actual invalid cases by prohibiting to override `M` once it has been set to a concrete type. Which is kind-of exactly the reason why I failed to come up with a counter-example that would demonstrate that the overly conservative estimate of the actual type is really necessary.